# ANDROID : BasicSyncAdapter with parser JSON ANDROID

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, android-syncadapter

i am block on a problem and i need your expertise.

I downloaded the BasicSyncAdapter of Android , on [here](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-stub-provider.html)
and i succeeded to use it on my android projet, BUT it's work with FeedParser in **XML**...
And i would like to work with **JSON** data, so with parser JSON.I found many library like Jackson, Gson..
But i'm afraid to blow all.

So can you help me about this parser..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use your JSON parser using [Android JSON parser](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) to parse your data. You can edit BasicSyncAdapter source code and instead of FeedParser use your own JSON data parser, also make sure you include license information.